# debate over JSON and XML

Tags: json

I am reading the debate over JSON and XML 
And i am not  sure why JSON seems to have come out of nowhere to threaten precious XML

And one of the point mentioned is

JSON is a better fit for Web services that power Web mashups and AJAX widgets due to the fact that it is essentially serialized Javascript objects. That’s it. XML will never fit the bill as well for these scenarios without changes to the existing browser ecosystem which I doubt are forthcoming anytime soon.

**Could you please tell me what is the exact meaning of this ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In really short: It is simpler to use JSON than XML in a lot of scenarios (because it consists of serialized JS objects just as you said) and also it provides faster data transfer over the network (and that comes from the not so or less redundant data structures of it, compared to XML).
Regards, Peter

Answer (score 1):

JSON doesn't require html-like markup with opening and closing tags (lots of unneeded code), can be easily fit into JS as it's almost a native JS object sintax, code it's easier to read and to maintain. It's also easier to modify during run-time.

Anyway, for tree-like structures, deep nested children and/or complex structures, I think XML is best suited for the job. JSON is better for data transfer/exchange.